# what is the result of this linux command

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I came across the following shell in Linux,

```
alias   eg    'env | grep \!*'
```

After sourcing the above she'll, The result of executing this
    eg apple
Is to show all lines that contains "apple"

I have no clue what is the syntax behind !*, can someone help explain?
Please be specific on each sign. like what does backslash do, as well as exclamation and *

Answer (score 1):

Backslash turns the exclamation mark into a literal, otherwise it would be a history expansion character in bash. Asterisk means "repeated zero or more times".

Comment: Thanks Choroba, so this means finding out the lines that contain '!' or anything starts with '!*', right?

Comment: @engineerdaniel not exactly. It shows all lines containing zero or more exclamation marks, i.e. all the lines.

Comment: I have modified the question to be more specific. The result is not as expected. It is not showing all lines containing zero or more exclamation signs

Comment: @EngineerDaniel: What shell do you use?

Comment: It is in the .cshrc file, so I assume it is cshell

Comment: @EngineerDaniel: Ah, ok, my explanation was for bash. I'm not familiar with cshell.